# I want to print "Apple" and "tomato" using findElement(By.className())

Tags: html, selenium, css-selectors, element

Here is the sample of some tags. I would like to print "Apple" and "tomato" using `findElement(By.className())`.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZAOO.png)

```
<div class="divclass">
    <div class="child_divclass1">
        <span class="span_1">fruits</span>
        <span>Apple</span>
    </div>
    <div class="child_divclass2">
        <span class="span_2">vegetables</span>
        </span><span>tomato</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not possible as there is no `class` name associated with the target `span` element. 
Moreover, there is an extra `span` tag near "tomato" text.

Comment: it's not possible using only className() but you could use that function to get the parent and then perhaps figure out a way to retrieve the 2nd child of each of the elements you found. As Swaroop mentioned you will have to fix the syntax error first.

Answer (score 0):

Using **xpath**

You can make use of xpath selector. try the below xpath

```
//div[@class="child_divclass1"]//span[2]
```

Sample code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"child_divclass1\"]//span[2]"));
```

Will work as shown in image below

[image]

Using CSS selector

```
.child_divclass1 span:nth-of-type(2)
```

Sample code

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".child_divclass1 span:nth-of-type(2)"));
```

**Using ClassName**

As per your need, you want to select the element by [classname](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/locators-in-selenium-webdriver-with-examples/#:%7E:text=Class%20Name%20Locator%20In%20Selenium,is%20located%20via%20class%20name.) but this is not possible with normal selenium selector method since there is no class name in second `span` tag

For this we can use `JavascriptExecutor` to add the class name for this tag and based on the class name we can use that in selector as shown below

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
String custom_classname="span_2";
js.executeScript("document.querySelector('.child_divclass1 span:nth-of-type(2)').classList.add('"+custom_classname+"')",2000);
WebElement txt1=driver.findElement(By.className(custom_classname));
System.out.println(txt1.getText());
```

Snapshot for your reference
[image]

Comment: Thanks. but I want to do it by using By.className(). can you help me with that. thanks again